# How to ajax a whole form using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I have set up a jquery script to submit a form and I want to grab the response (which I believe is a whole page, albiet small) and use the content of the response to replace the form (as the response is just the form).

here is my jquery script:

```
$("#addPersonButton").click(function(){
    $.post("/MySite/MyAjaxServlet.do", $("#personForm").serialize(), function( data ) {
        var content = $( data );
        $( "#personForm" ).empty().append( content );
    });
});
```

however the output on my page appears as "[object Object]"

How can I replace the form in my page with the form returned on the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
$( "#personForm" ).empty().append( data );
```

Answer (score 2):

`html` method replace the contents of matched selector

```
$( "#personForm" ).html( data );
```

Comment: Hm. Now is this method quicker?

Comment: Doh! - now that its working I lose the bind of the click even on the add person button as its on the form.

Comment: `html` because is  2x faster than using `empty` and `append` together and is more clearly. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nFfSx/
.You can use `live` instead `click` - this will attach listener to event on present elements and which will exist in the future

Comment: With the new jQuery came `on` and `off` methods which are a consequence of the `bind`,`live`,`unbind` and `die`. Read about this on http://api.jquery.com/on/